# How to see code of a stored Procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have made multiple procedures in pl/sql oracle, using **APEX**.

> I want to see `pl/sql code` for my Procedures.

**I need a query to do this operation**, not through wizards and stuff.

Kindly help me?

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the solution.
Very simple.

```
SELECT TEXT 
FROM USER_SOURCE 
WHERE NAME = 'PROCEDURE NAME';
```

Note that procedure name **must be in capitals.**

For example:

```
SELECT TEXT 
FROM USER_SOURCE 
WHERE NAME = 'SELECTION_SORT';
```